# htaccess 301 Redirect to subdomain in wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a problem with redirection on my website.
I don't know how built file htaccess.

now:
www.mydomain/folder/value1/value2

resault:
[www.folder.mydomain/value1/value2](http://www.folder.mydomain/value1/value2)

May You help? I try many solution.

Comment: Please, try to provide more details about your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I have apache server developed by outside provider, and I have not full access to all options.

.HTACCESS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^zloteapartamenty\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://zloteapartamenty.ritex-development.pl/$0 [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Old url:
https://ritex-development.pl/zloteapartamenty/pietro/pietro-iii/
Bad new ulr:
http://zloteapartamenty.ritex-development.pl/pietro-iii/
Expected new url:
https://zloteapartamenty.ritex-development.pl/pietro/pietro-iii/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).